# Too many values to unpack using NLTK and Pandas in Python

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I am trying out different things to make the NLTK's naive bayes work using the NLTK and Pandas modules, but I am getting the "too many values to unpack" error.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import numpy as np
import re
import nltk

### Remove cases with missing name or missing ethnicity information
def read_file():
    data = pd.read_csv("C:\sample.csv", encoding="utf-8")
    frame = DataFrame(data)
    frame.columns = ["Name", "Gender"]

    return frame
#read_file()

def gender_features(word):
    return {'last_letter': word[-1]}
#gender_features()

frame = read_file()
featuresets = [(gender_features(n), gender) for (n, gender) in frame]
train_set, test_set = features[500:], featuresets[:500]
classifier = nltkNaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

Comment: at which line are you getting the error? Can you give two sample lines from your `sample.csv`?

Comment: BTW, caught you for duplicating the question after no one answered your old one.

Comment: also your code doesn't compile and run...

Comment: Thanks, I am very new in both Pandas and nltk, I put down the code aside for a coupld days and thought I was trying something new, the two posts are different as I am trying some example dataset and my own dataset, but in retrospect they don't deserve to be two distinct posts, I have deleted the previous, hope it's removed from public view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to do something bigger than name classification when using `panadas.DataFrame` because the `DataFrame` object is normally used when you have limited RAM and wants to makes use of diskspace as you iterate through the data to extract features:

> a 2-dimensional labeled data structure with columns of potentially
>   different types. You can think of it like a spreadsheet or SQL table,
>   or a dict of Series objects. It is generally the most commonly used
>   pandas object. Like Series, DataFrame accepts many different kinds of
>   input:
>
> - Dict of 1D ndarrays, lists, dicts, or Series
> - 2-D numpy.ndarray
> - Structured or record ndarray
> - A Series
> - Another DataFrame

I suggest you go through the `pandas` tutorial to learn about the library first: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/tutorials.html

And then learn about the NLTK classification from http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html

---

Firstly, there are several things wrong in how you access `pandas.DataFrame` object.

To iterate through the rows of the dataframe, you should do this:

```
# Read file into pandas dataframe
df = DataFrame(pd.read_csv('sample.csv'))
df.columns = ['name', 'gender']

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print row['name'], row['gender']
```

Next to train a classifier, you should do this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

from nltk.corpus import names
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier as nbc

# Create a sample.csv file
male_names = [','.join([i,'m']) for i in names.words('male.txt')]
female_names = [','.join([i,'m']) for i in names.words('female.txt')]
with open('sample.csv', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write('\n'.join(male_names+female_names))

# Feature extractor function.
def gender_features(word):
    return {'last_letter': word[-1]}

# Read file into pandas dataframe
df = DataFrame(pd.read_csv('sample.csv'))
df.columns = ['name', 'gender']

# Extract features. 
featuresets = [(gender_features(name), gender) for index, (name, gender) in df.iterrows()]
# Split train and test set
train_set, test_set = featuresets[500:], featuresets[:500]
# Train a classifier
classifier = nbc.train(train_set)
# Test classifier on "Neo"
print classifier.classify(gender_features('Neo'))
```

[out]:

```
m
```